# Cross validation using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use Cross-validation on using spark but it throws an error:

```
gbtClassifier = GBTClassifier(featuresCol= "features", labelCol="is_goal")
lr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol= "features" ,labelCol="is_goal")
pipelineStages = stringIndexers + encoders + [featureAssembler]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=pipelineStages)

param_grid_lr = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1,0.01]).addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0,0.5,1]).build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, estimatorParamMaps=param_grid_lr ,evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(), numFolds=3)

cross_model = crossval.fit(df_tr)
```

IllegalArgumentException: label does not exist. Available: event_type_str, event_team, shot_place_str, location_str, assist_method_str, situation_str, country_code, is_goal, event_type_str_idx, event_team_idx, shot_place_str_idx, location_str_idx, assist_method_str_idx, situation_str_idx, country_code_idx, event_type_str_vec, event_team_vec, shot_place_str_vec, location_str_vec, assist_method_str_vec, situation_str_vec, country_code_vec, features, CrossValidator_2fc516202d9d_rand, rawPrediction, probability, prediction

[here is who my features look like[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkg2k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `BinaryClassificationEvaluator` expects by default that the label column is called `label` as you can see from the docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator .
You'll need to specify `rawPredictionCol` and `labelCol` according to the columns given in your dataframe

Comment: Thanks! it worked, i renamed the 'is_goal' Column to label and it worked